# 97 chevy tahoe puttering clicking

Tags: chevrolet, noise, tahoe

I have a 1997 Chevy Tahoe the engine is making a puttering sound it smokes a little bit from I don't know where and there's a clicking sound what could this be

Comment: puttering sound?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!  It actually does run? This is the 350 small block?